# What's the best way to remove a light coating of rust from a carbon steel paella pan?

Tags: carbon-steel

I was recently given a carbon steel paella pan with a very light coating of rust (its prior owner hadn't known how to care for carbon steel, and gave it to me and bought a stainless one).  There are quite a number of ways to remove rust, and I'm wondering which one will work the best?

- I have a jar of Naval Jelly, which I use to remove rust from garden tools.  However, carbon steel knife forums warn that Naval Jelly can be too strong and etch the carbon steel.
- A vinegar bath is another method (as well as other acid baths such as citric acid).  However, the paella pan is 15" in diameter, and I don't have a large enough basin to soak it in, nor am I eager to buy 3 gallons of vinegar.
- Some people simply scrub off the rust with steel wool.  I'm concerned that this will scratch up the paella pan, which is otherwise fairly pristine.
- Brasso is milder than Naval Jelly, so I was thinking of just using a tube of that.  It's not, however, primarily a rust remover.
- It's possible that scrubbing with Barkeeper's Friend would take the rust off as well.  But it's also possible it won't.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with Barkeeper's Friend. That has worked for me in the past.  Use it with a synthetic scrub pad.  As you know, once you get it in shape to use it, after cleaning, a light coating of oil wiped on with a paper towel will keep the rust from reappearing during storage.

Comment: Tested and proven to be the correct approach.  I now have a rust-free and seasoned paella pan.  Thanks, moscafj!

Comment: @FuzzyChef Excellent!  How do I get some of that paella?

Comment: Come to Portland, OR!